# Trouble using the UART with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, c, code, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm making a remote controlled machine using a Raspberry Pi Pico to drive the motors and read some sensors, and a Raspberry Pi 4 to send commands to the Pico via serial and host the web interface.

I'm working on sending and receiving commands from the Raspberry and for now I'm stuck with this code:

```c
#include <string.h>

#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/uart.h"
#include "hardware/irq.h"

#define UART_ID uart0
#define BAUD_RATE 19200
#define DATA_BITS 8
#define STOP_BITS 1
#define PARITY    UART_PARITY_NONE
#define UART_TX_PIN 0
#define UART_RX_PIN 1

static int chars_rxed = 0;

char uCommand[32] = {0, 0};

void on_uart_rx() {
    char tmp_string[] = {0, 0};
    while (uart_is_readable(UART_ID)) {
        uint8_t ch = uart_getc(UART_ID);
        tmp_string[0] = ch;
        strcat(uCommand, tmp_string);
        if(uart_is_writable(UART_ID)){
          uart_putc(UART_ID, '-');
          uart_puts(UART_ID, uCommand);
          uart_putc(UART_ID, '-');
        }
        chars_rxed++;
    }
}

int main(){

  uart_init(UART_ID, BAUD_RATE);

  gpio_set_function(UART_TX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);
  gpio_set_function(UART_RX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);
  uart_set_hw_flow(UART_ID, false, false);
  uart_set_format(UART_ID, DATA_BITS, STOP_BITS, PARITY);
  uart_set_fifo_enabled(UART_ID, false);

  int UART_IRQ = UART_ID == uart0 ? UART0_IRQ : UART1_IRQ;

  irq_set_exclusive_handler(UART_IRQ, on_uart_rx);
  irq_set_enabled(UART_IRQ, true);
  uart_set_irq_enables(UART_ID, true, false);

  uart_puts(UART_ID, "\nOK\n");
    while (1){
        tight_loop_contents();
        if(uCommand[0] != 0){
          uart_putc(UART_ID, '/');
          uart_puts(UART_ID, uCommand);
          uart_putc(UART_ID, '/');
        }
      }
}
```

My idea was to take the command sent via serial during the interrupt and place it in a charset, then parse it and execute it externally.

Trying it, I notice that it never enters the `if` inside the `while` and it doesn't 'fill' the 'uCommand' charset completely but only a few characters compared to the ones sent.

I hope my question is not off-topic.

***UPDATE***

I am extremely disconcerted.

The following code seems to work... but... If I remove the `if` with `is_uart_writable` coding and its content it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea why?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/uart.h"
#include "hardware/irq.h"

//DEFINES
#define UART_ID uart0
#define BAUD_RATE 19200
#define DATA_BITS 8
#define STOP_BITS 1
#define PARITY    UART_PARITY_NONE
#define UART_TX_PIN 0
#define UART_RX_PIN 1
#define LED_PIN PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN

static int chars_rxed = 0;

volatile char uCommand[32] = {0, 0};

void on_uart_rx(void) {
   char tmp_string[] = {0, 0};
   new_command = true;
   while (uart_is_readable(UART_ID)) {
       uint8_t ch = uart_getc(UART_ID);
       tmp_string[0] = ch;
       strcat(uCommand, tmp_string);
       if(uart_is_writable(UART_ID)){
         uart_putc(UART_ID, '-');
         uart_puts(UART_ID, uCommand);
         uart_putc(UART_ID, '-');
       }
       chars_rxed++;
   }
}

int main(){

 uart_init(UART_ID, BAUD_RATE);

 gpio_set_function(UART_TX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);
 gpio_set_function(UART_RX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);

 uart_set_hw_flow(UART_ID, false, false);

 uart_set_format(UART_ID, DATA_BITS, STOP_BITS, PARITY);

 uart_set_fifo_enabled(UART_ID, false);

 int UART_IRQ = UART_ID == uart0 ? UART0_IRQ : UART1_IRQ;

 irq_set_exclusive_handler(UART_IRQ, on_uart_rx);
 irq_set_enabled(UART_IRQ, true);

 uart_set_irq_enables(UART_ID, true, false);

 uart_puts(UART_ID, "\nOK\n");

   while (1){
       tight_loop_contents();
       if(uCommand[0] != 0){
         uart_putc(UART_ID, '/');
         uart_puts(UART_ID, uCommand);
         memset(uCommand, 0, sizeof(uCommand));
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the classic "missing volatile" bug. You should have `volatile char uCommand[32] = {0, 0};`.

I also don't see where you reset `uCommand` after the first reception.

In addition `void on_uart_rx()` is obsolete style and might be the wrong type if the callback expects `void func (void)`. Replace empty parenthesis with `(void)`.

Comment: Isn't it more of a problem if the callback expects something *other* than `void func(void)`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lundin. I added volatile in the array declaration, I tried to compile but unfortunately I got a couple of errors, on strcat and uart_puts, should I do some conversion before passing the array to it?

Comment: @OskarSkog `void f(void)` is as far as I remember, strictly speaking not compatible with `void f()`. Compilers tend to handle it in a well-defined manner though, but no guarantees.

Comment: @lasb3tas Depends on how picky you are with avoiding undefined behavior. The quick & dirty fix is to just cast to `char*`. If you need strictly conforming code, then it gets more complex.

Comment: @Lundin A `void foo();` declaration is obsolete style and means that `foo` and take any number arguments (it's up to the programmer to not screw it up, not to be confused with `va_arg`). // A `void foo(void);` declaration means that `foo` takes absolutely no arguments.  // `void foo() {}` and `void foo(void) {}` will both *define* the same function that doesn't take any arguments, but the latter also gives it a "prototype".

Comment: @Lundin The obsolete style will work when called without arguments, but calling it with an argument may be undefined behavior.  The explicit style causes a compilation error if an argument is passed to the function.  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319492/understanding-the-difference-between-f-and-fvoid-in-c-and-c-once-and-for-a

Comment: @OskarSkog The question here is if function pointers to the different functions are compatible with each other. I believe this is a case where the C language applies a weird rule called composite type. I don't remember all the details. For non-language lawyers it's sufficient to simply not write obsolete C and don't worry about why exactly obsolete C is bad.

Comment: They should be compatible, that's what composite types are for. But I do agree that function prototypes should be used.